# Aggregate count for unique columns per id

Tags: sql, count, group-by, aggregate

I need a query that can aggregate data from different columns in a table.
I need the count of distinct person_ids per file and count of distinct token_nrs per file.

I'm currently using the following queries:

```
SELECT file.id, COUNT(t1.person_id) FROM file JOIN 
(SELECT file_id, person_id FROM data GROUP BY file_id, person_id) 
t1 ON t1.file_id = file.ID GROUP BY file.id

SELECT file.id, COUNT(t1.token_tr) FROM file JOIN 
(SELECT file_id, token_nr FROM data GROUP BY file_id, token_nr) 
t1 ON t1.file_id = file.ID GROUP BY file.id
```

Currently I perform the query for both aggregations and then combine the rows in python to get [id, count(person_id), count(token)].

Is there a simpler way to do this in pure SQL?

Table structures

```
 File
id  name
1   file1.txt
2   file2.txt

Data
id  file_id     person_id   token_nr
1   1           1           43
2   1           2           69  
3   1           1           55
4   2           1           44


Results
File.id     count(unique person_ids)    count(unique token_nrs)
1           2                           3
2           1                           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct column_name)` to get the # of distinct column values per file id

```
select f.id, count(distinct person_id), count(distinct token_nr)
from file f 
join data d on f.id = d.file_id
group by f.id
```

Comment: I'm curious, is it possible to do this using group by instead of distinct?

Comment: @dani-h don't understand your question. this query uses both `group by` and `distinct` because you want the # of distinct person_id and token_nr per file id group.

Comment: I've read other posts where they pose group by as an alternative to distinct. I'm asking because I'm wrapping the query with SQLAlchemy and I'm not sure how to use distinct there :>

Comment: Nevermind it works fine with SQLAlchemy using func.count(distinct)) when selecting the row. Thank you @FuzzyTree!